# Why the "adb shell monkey --wait-dbg" doesn't work?

Tags: android, adb, monkey

I want to stop the running monkey by using the `adb shell monkey --wait-dbg`,but the result is only display like this:`Sending WAIT chunk`and then the monkey is still running.
How to understand the command?The official explain is "Stops the Monkey from executing until a debugger is attached to it."

Comment: Try `adb shell ps | awk '/com\.android\.commands\.monkey/ { system("adb shell kill " $2) }'`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I know this way to stop monkey .I just want to understand this command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to why your command did not work, but you reported this as working:

```
adb shell ps | awk '/com\.android\.commands\.monkey/ { system("adb shell kill " $2) }'
```

This is a linux command line.

Let me explains it: it displays all running processes (ps), filter it to get the process id of "com.android.commands.monkey" (awk) then sends it a SIGTERM signal (kill).

- [ps(1)](http://www.manpages.info/linux/ps.1.html) lists running processus.
- [kill(1)](http://www.manpages.info/linux/kill.1.html) sends a SIGTERM signal from the linux kernel directly to the process you targeted.